# Conditionally require all fields in class depending on property

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Address class, which is used for two properties - MailingAddress and StreetAddress.

How can I make StreetAddress required and MailingAddress not?

```
    public Address MailingAddress { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address, city, state, and zip code are required.")]
    public Address StreetAddress { get; set; }


 public class Address
    {
        [DisplayName("Address")]
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("City")]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("State")]     
        public string SelectedState { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d{5}$|^\d{5}-\d{4}$", ErrorMessage="The postal code should be in the format 00000 or 00000-0000")]
        [DisplayName("Zip")]
        public string Zip { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would treat them a little differently. I propose we have two different address models and put them into a single viewModel.

Let's take your `Address` class and give it some `virtual` keywords so we can override the class properties.

```
public class Address
{
    [DisplayName("Address")]
    public virtual string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("City")]
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("State")]     
    public virtual string SelectedState { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d{5}$|^\d{5}-\d{4}$", ErrorMessage="The postal code should be in the format 00000 or 00000-0000")]
    [DisplayName("Zip")]
    public virtual string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's create a new model that inherits our Address class.

```
public class MandatoryAddress : Address
{
    [Required]
    public override string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public override string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public override string SelectedState { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public override string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's create our **viewModel**

```
public class MyFormViewModel
{
    public MandatoryAddress StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public Address MailingAddress { get; set; }
}
```

A **view** might look like this

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Sample Form";
}

@model TestApp.Models.MyFormViewModel

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Street Address</legend>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.StreetAddress.StreetAddress)
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.StreetAddress.StreetAddress)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.StreetAddress.StreetAddress)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.StreetAddress.City)
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.StreetAddress.City)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.StreetAddress.City)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.StreetAddress.SelectedState)
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.StreetAddress.SelectedState)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.StreetAddress.SelectedState)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.StreetAddress.Zip)
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.StreetAddress.Zip)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.StreetAddress.Zip)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Mailing Address</legend>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.MailingAddress.StreetAddress)
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.MailingAddress.StreetAddress)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.MailingAddress.StreetAddress)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.MailingAddress.City)
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.MailingAddress.City)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.MailingAddress.City)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.MailingAddress.SelectedState)
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.MailingAddress.SelectedState)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.MailingAddress.SelectedState)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.MailingAddress.Zip)
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.MailingAddress.Zip)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.MailingAddress.Zip)
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
}
```

A **controller** might look like this:

```
public class FormController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Form/

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyFormViewModel viewModel = new MyFormViewModel();
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyFormViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }

}
```

*Bonus experience points*:

An alternative way (more complex but arguably 'better') is to create your own custom `[Required]` attribute that you can apply to a class (i.e. `StreetAddress`). The attribute would have to go through each property of the class and apply a `[Required]` attribute.

Comment: Thank you Rowan. Regarding the 'expert' solution, would the attribute be specific to my Address class, or a generic [Required] attribute that can be used for any class? Might you have an example?

Comment: After having a look into it, that method is even more complicated than I expected. Mostly likely so complex that it would actually be a bad direction to go in. Models are typically transparent (they easily reveal everything about themselves to you) and they're also very small which usually means it's ok to have them repeat a little. The key is to be obvious in what your intention is. With this in mind, stick with my code examples above.